# auto click em site de terceiros pegando o botao e armazenando em variavel

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Para vocês entenderem:

Ola boa noite, estou finalizando um curso de programação e esse é o meu trabalho de web em construção http://www.indicovoce.esy.es
até ae tudo bem, estou estudando Java Script e JQuery e to com o estudo do auto click, sem mais delongas.
quero criar um código para auto click em site de terceiros, e esse site de terceiros no caso é o meu indicovoce.
criei um outro site to usando o comando do `php file_get_contents`   para pegar a pagina que eu quero, com o codigo em mãos para pegar uma parte especifica 
to usando

```
$pattern = "/Inscreva-se/i"; 
if pegou alguma informações
if ($resultado >= 1) {
print "funcionou";
echo ' <script>
window.setTimeout(function(){
document.getElementById("botao_2").click();*   <-- esse é o comando do click.

}, 500);
</script>';
var_dump($matches);
```

**EDIT:** até onde pesquisei, nao da pra fazer o auto click em site de terceiros, porque a pagina precisa ter um codigo java script, entao pensei em armazenar o código do botao em uma variavel e tentar acionar por ali,  sera possivel?

espero que ficou bem claro, oque vocês puderem ajudar agradeço muito.)

PHP:

```
<?php
echo ' <script src="jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>';
$url = file_get_contents('http://www.indicovoce.esy.es/_cadastro/cad_cliente.php');
$pattern = "/Inscreva-se/i";
$matches = array();

# Executa nossa expressão
$resultado = preg_match_all($pattern, $url, $matches);

if ($resultado >= 1) {
    print "funcionou";
echo '  <script>
         window.setTimeout(function(){
                document.getElementById("botao_2").click();

            }, 500);
        </script>';
    var_dump($matches);

} else if ($resultado === 0) {
    print "nãofuncionou";
    var_dump($matches);
    preg_last_error();

} elseif ($resultado === false) {
    print "ocorreu um erro";

}

?>
```

Comment: Marlos, sua pergunta está um pouco confusa, apesar de dar pra entender a intenção geral. Sugeriria uma lida no [Tour], em [Ask] e depois com calma a [Help] para um melhor aproveitamento do site. Lembrando que sempre você pode [Edit] suas postagens para fazer os ajustes necessários ou complementos.

Comment: eu pesquisei e nao achei nado do tipo armazenar o codigo do botao em uma variavel e por ali acionar o auto click. ja tentei e nao funcionou, mas queria saber se é possivel.